# Интерфейс в Win32 API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gcc

[image: Вот такая кнопка создается]Есть окно, созданное на Win32 API в C++, и когда я создаю элементы интерфейса по туториалу из microsoft docs, например кнопку, она имеет отличающийся вид от тех кнопок, которые создаются в .NET Framework (т. е. стандартные кнопки в windows). Вот код кнопки:

```
HWND hwndButton = CreateWindow( 
"BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
"OK",      // Button text 
WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
0,         // x position 
0,         // y position 
60,        // Button width
20,        // Button height
hwnd,     // Parent window
NULL,       // No menu.
(HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), 
NULL);
```

В чем вопрос - как создать кнопку, на Win32, которая будет оформляться под разные видновс по-своему (точно как в .NET Framework)
А вот такие кнопки я хочу создать (как Settings... , View... и тд)
[image: А вот такие кнопки я хочу создать (как Settings... , View... и тд)]

Comment: Так и создавать, это и есть стандартные кнопки windows.

Comment: @user7860670 но я ни разу не видел таких кнопок в софте для виндовс, везде либо кнопки как в .net, либо кастомные

Comment: картинки бы чтоли добавили, тут телепатов нет...

Comment: В манифесте нужно поменять версию Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls на шестую

Comment: и high DPI awareness прописать... Кстати это самые стандартные кнопки.

Answer (score 6):

тебе надо будет сделать следующие шаги:

1. добавить подключение заголовка CommCtrl.h в самом начале твоего проекта;

   `#include <CommCtrl.h>`
2. в твоей функции `WinMain` в любом месте до создания основного окна приложения написать код инициализации этой библиотеки Common Controls:

   ```
   INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX pInitCommonControlsEx;

   pInitCommonControlsEx.dwSize = sizeof (INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
   pInitCommonControlsEx.dwICC = ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES;

   InitCommonControlsEx (&pInitCommonControlsEx);
   ```
3. указать линкеру использовать файл comctl32.lib.
   если пишешь на Visual C++, то это можно сделать одним из двух способов:

   1. непосредственно в коде после подключения хэдеров (`#include...`) написать директиву препроцессора для линкера:

      ```
      #pragma comment (lib, "comctl32.lib")
      ```
   2. изменить настройки проекта:

      1. в меню «Project» среды разработки выбрать пункт «<имя проекта> Properties...»;
      2. в появившемся окошке в дереве слева выбрать «Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input»;
      3. в списке справа в строке «Additional Dependencies» в список уже указанных библиотек добавить `comctl32.lib` (не забывать разделять имена библиотек точкой с запятой `;`).
4. указать линкеру использовать именно 6ую версию библиотеки Common Controls.
   если пишешь на Visual C++, то это можно сделать одним из двух способов:

   1. непосредственно в коде после подключения заголовков (`#include...`) написать директиву препроцессора для линкера:

   ```
   #pragma comment (linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
   ```

   2. изменить настройки проекта:

      1. в меню «Project» среды разработки выбрать пункт «<имя проекта> Properties...»;
      2. в появившемся окошке в дереве слева выбрать «Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Manifest File»;
      3. в списке справа в строке «Additional Manifest Dependencies» в выпадающем списке выбрать пункт «<Edit...>»;
      4. в ещё одном появившемся окошке в самом верхнем текстовом поле написать:

      ```
      type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'
      ```

      5. нажать на кнопку «ОК»;

---

возможно, а точнее скорее всего, шрифт надписи на кнопке будет по умолчанию использован не тот, что у тебя на скриншоте, на котором ты показал желаемые тобой кнопки. если так, то тебе надо будет указать кнопке использовать системный шрифт, для этого тебе снова придЁтся написать немного кода:

1. объявить глобальную переменную для хэндла шрифта:

   ```
   HFONT hFontButton;
   ```
2. в оконной процедуре обработки сообщений основного окна для сообщения `WM_CREATE`, где по идее должна создаваться кнопка, написать код, который получает параметры системного шрифта, затем создаЁт шрифт по этим параметрам и потом его (шрифт) передаЁт кнопке:

   ```
   // объявление структуры для получения системных параметров
   NONCLIENTMETRICS pNonClientMetrics;

   pNonClientMetrics.cbSize = sizeof (NONCLIENTMETRICS);

   // получение некоторых системных данных, где указаны параметры системного шрифта
   SystemParametersInfo (SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, sizeof (NONCLIENTMETRICS), &pNonClientMetrics, 0);

   // создание шрифта
   hFontButton = CreateFontIndirect (&pNonClientMetrics.lfMenuFont);

   // создание кнопки
   hWndButton = CreateWindowEx (0, "BUTTON", "Process", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, 5, 5, 100, 24, hWnd, (HMENU) 101, NULL, NULL);

   // передача шрифта кнопке
   SendMessage (hWndButton, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) hFontButton, TRUE);
   ```
3. в оконной процедуре обработки сообщений основного окна для сообщения `WM_DESTROY` необходимо уничтожить шрифт, который ранее был создан для кнопки.

   ВАЖНО: код уничтожения шрифта должен быть написан до кода передачи сообщения о завершении работы приложения:

   ```
   // уничтожение шрифта
   DeleteObject (hFontButton);

   // поместить в очередь сообщений сообщение о выходе из приложения с кодом ошибки 0 (нет ошибки)
   PostQuitMessage (0);
   ```